# Locked out from Dell u2711 menu - need to change input cable

Tags: hdmi, external-display, displayport, lock

I have a monitor which I used to use with a laptop with a DisplayPort video out. This laptop broke and cannot be started any longer.

I now have a new laptop and want to use the monitor again. The new laptop has a HDMI output. Luckily the monitor has just about any video input you can think of, so I bought a HDMI cabel and tried using it. Sadly, it appears that I have somehow "locked" the monitor - when I press the button for the OSD menu, I see a closed padlock icon in the middle of the display.

I read threads on the Dell support forums that address this issue ([1](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/monitor-how-to-unlock/td-p/3431388), [2](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U2711-OSD-locked/td-p/3688013), [3](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/U2711-Locked-on-a-different-input/td-p/5074521)). For some users, it appears that pressing the fifth button (or a combination of the fourth and fifth button) and holding for 15 seconds unlocks the menu. For me, this didn't work. The fourth button seems to not recognize the press (it is a near-sensing technology whose LED lights up when it senses a finger). The fifth button recognizes my finger. But long before the 15 seconds are over, the padlock is replaced by a "No DisplayPort Cable" message and it never turns to an open padlock (I timed it up to 60 seconds, tried different combinations of buttons, and also licked my fingers to increase conductivity).

The moderators over there have a canned answer for resetting the monitor which involves a 5 second press of the on/off switch while everything is disconnected (no power too!) then connecting to the power and to the computer. I suppose it is the "connect to the computer" part that spoils it for me - since I cannot connect to a DisplayPort cable, I again get the "No DisplayPort cable" message and as always, the menu button only turns up the padlock, so I can't choose a different input. It appears that I'm not the first one to run into that - the third thread I linked experiences the same problem, and is unsolved.

I am not planning to buy an adapter for HDMI-to-DisplayPort (if these exist at all) and I don't have access to a computer with a DisplayPort output. How do I get to use the monitor again?

Answer (score 0):

I have just unlocked my monitor and sharing my experience with you.

Firstly, you have to show something on your Dell monitor (for your case via the DisplayPort of your monitor).

You can connect using any device and not necessarily a laptop. It can be a PC, TV box, cell phone and etc. the has a display output port. You might need a cable adapter to convert to DisplayPort.

So while something is being displayed on the Dell monitor screen, you press the Exit button (for Dell u2711 is the 5th button from top) and hold it for about 15 seconds. Release the button when you see an open padlock image on the screen.

Just remember, when there is no display on the screen, pressing the button on the monitor for 15 seconds will NOT unlock your monitor.

This method solved my problem. Maybe there are other method that works too that i am not aware of. Hope this method solve you problem.